# Problem with python selenium google scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

```
import time
import csv

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


search_input = [str(input("Введите запрос/запросы:\n"))]
limit = int(input("Введите лимит ответов:\n"))
result = [item.split(' ') for item in search_input]
result_flat = [item for l in result for item in l]


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.165 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("accept=*/*")

s = Service(executable_path='C:\Program Files\google_answers')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
  '''
})


driver.maximize_window()

data=[]
def search(url):
        driver.get(url)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
        topic = soup.find_all(class_="CSkcDe")
        topic_string = [item.string for item in topic]
        row = soup.find_all(class_="hgKElc") 
        row_string = [item.text for item in row]
        data = [topic_string,row_string]
        with open("answers.xls","a+",encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=' ',quotechar=" ")
            i = 0
            for items in data:
                 while i<len(items):
                    writer.writerow(f"{topic_string[i],row_string[i]}")  
                    i += 1            


def main():
    for i in range(0,len(result_flat)):
        search(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={result_flat[i]}&rlz=1C1YTUH_ruKZ1054KZ1060&oq={result_flat[i]}&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i433i512j0i512j0i131i433i512l2j0i512l2j46i512j0i512l2.1332j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8https://www.google.com/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am also interested in saving data with h1,h2,p,li tags to .xls file. I assume that i need to use click() function, but I relly can't realize how to copy data from google fast search[image].Please add some description to your changes, if it possible.My programm only returns first 4 answers. Also i can't scrap columns(

tags etc.)

Comment: you can use the selenium for that, please check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Selenium for clicking and then getting the content. The content is visible after the click action, under `div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)` so the code should looks like this

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
h1 = soup.find(name="q").string

contents = []
h2s = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[class='related-question-pair']")
for item in h2s:
  item.click()
  content = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)")
  
  contents.append([item.text, content.text])
```